# passing parameter in wcf service through get method not working

Tags: wcf

i am working on wcf service where i want to return subcategories based on parent category selection.

this is my interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface iServiceRegistration
    {
        [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET")]
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSubCategories(int categoryId);
    }

    public class Service : iServiceRegistration 
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSubCategories(int categoryId)
        {
                           //code
        }
     }
```

i am using REST Client of mozilla to test this service.now when i am calling this method from rest client like this:

```
{
 "categoryId": "1"
}
```

then 0 is coming in my parameter categoryId.

can anybody tell me whats the problem?????

Comment: Try: {  "categoryId": 1 }

Comment: not working and i dont think so problem is this(means parameter passing from rest client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the method to be `GET` (as an aside, don't use `[WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]`; use `[WebGet]` instead). Parameters in GET requests are passed in the query string, not in the request body. You should either change the client (REST client) to send the following request:

```
GET http://your-service/endpoint/GetSubCategories?categoryId=1
```

Or change the method to accept `POST` requests:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStype = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSubCategories(int categoryId);
```

And send the request in the body of a POST call:

```
POST http://your-service/endpoint/GetSubCategories
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: XXX

{"categoryId":1}
```

Comment: +1 for your explanation but i dont have sufficient point to vote and thank u so much for ur ans

Answer (score 0):

You missed **UriTemplate** and in get method you need to pass parameter in url.
so your call should be like

**http://yourservice.svc/UriTemplate/parameter**